# Emboss a Path representing image on android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing

I am trying to draw an image on a Path (which is a closed irregular shape). I have used **PorterDuffXfermode**. My objective is to use **EmbossMaskFilter** and create a emboss effect on the final image shape output. See the code below. However, even I draw the piecePicture it looks flat.

```
piecePicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

MaskFilter mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
Canvas gfx = new Canvas(piecePicture);


Paint whitePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
whitePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
whitePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);

// shape image has to take
mPath.addRect(10, 10, 195, 195, Direction.CCW);
gfx.drawPath(mPath, whitePaint);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
paint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);   
// draw the image on path viewBgrnd is the bitmap    
gfx.drawBitmap(viewBgrnd, 10,10, paint);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After drawing the image using PorterDuffXfermode.
piecePicture has to be redrawn on a canvas using a Paint Object with emboss filter.